# Terraform - Consume for_each module output as input to another module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm having trouble referencing the output of a module as an input to another module.
I'm trying to output network_interface_id from vm.tf, and use it as input to lb.tf.

I get the error, each.value is tuple with 2 elements, Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_id": string required.

It works if I use network_interface_id = each.value[0], or[1] but obviously only adds one nic to the lb.

I've been going round in circles trying to figure this out so any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance ... :-)

This is the snippet of code I'm struggling with from lb.tf. Full code is below that.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nibapa" {
  for_each                = var.nic_ids
  network_interface_id    = each.value # <= This errors with each.value is tuple with 2 elements. It works using each.value[0] or [1]; but I need to loop through both.
  ip_configuration_name   = "internal"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lbap.id
}
```

main.tf

```
locals {
  vm = {
    "01" = {
      zone = "1"
    }
    "02" = {
      zone = "2"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  location                        = "northeurope"
  name                            = "rg-test1"
}

module "vm" {
  source                          = "./vm"
  for_each                        = local.vm
  location                        = "northeurope"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  vm_name                         = "vm-${each.key}"
  nic_name                        = "nic-vm-${each.key}"
  os_disk_name                    = "osdisk-vm-${each.key}"
  availability_zone               = each.value.zone
}

output "nic_ids" { value = [ for k, nic in module.vm : nic.nic_id ] }

module "lb" {
  source                          = "./lb"
  location                        = "northeurope"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  nic_ids                         = { value = [ for k, nic in module.vm : nic.nic_id ] }
}
```

vm.tf

```
variable "location" {}
variable "resource_group_name" {}
variable "vm_name" {}
variable "nic_name" {}
variable "os_disk_name" {}
variable "availability_zone" {}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "ni" {
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  name                = var.nic_name
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = "/subscriptions/2bc7b65e-18d6-42ae-afb2-e66d50be6b05/resourceGroups/rg-core-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-prd-spoke-nteu-01/subnets/snet-app"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "lvm" {
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  name                = var.vm_name
  size                = "Standard_B2ms"
  zone                = var.availability_zone
  admin_username      = "ladmin"
  admin_password      = "Password1234"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.ni.id,
  ]
  os_disk {
    name                 = var.os_disk_name
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

output "nic_id" { value = azurerm_network_interface.ni.id }
```

lb.tf

```
variable "location" {}
variable "resource_group_name" {}
variable "nic_ids" {}

resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  location                        = var.location
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  name                            = "lbi-test1"
  sku                             = "Standard"
  sku_tier                        = "Regional"
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "feip-test1"
    subnet_id                     = "/subscriptions/2bc7b65e-18d6-42ae-afb2-e66d50be6b05/resourceGroups/rg-core-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-prd-spoke-nteu-01/subnets/snet-app"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "lbap" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.lb.id
  name            = "beap-test1"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nibapa" {
  for_each                = var.nic_ids
  network_interface_id    = each.value # <= This errors with each.value is tuple with 2 elements. It works using each.value[0] or [1]; but I need to loop through both.
  ip_configuration_name   = "internal"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lbap.id
}
```

The error code is:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

   on lb\lb.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nibapa":
   25:   network_interface_id    = each.value
         each.value is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_id": string required.
```

Comment: What is the full error message, showing exactly line and line number where it occurs?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I've added to the main question body as formatting is better.

Comment: Does the output work as expected? If so, I think you only need to use `for_each                = toset(var.nic_ids)` in the `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association` resource.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out in the end.  The key changes were mainly syntactical ...

main.tf
The key line here is 'nic_ids = module.vm'. This returns a map of nic_id's for each instance.

```
module "lb" {
  depends_on                      = [ module.vm ]
  source                          = "./lb"
  location                        = "northeurope"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  nic_ids                         = module.vm
}
```

output "nic_ids" { value = module.vm }; (so the output of the variable nic_ids to pass to the next module looks like this)

```
nic_ids = {
  "01" = {
    "nic_id" = "/subscriptions/2bc7b65e-18d6-42ae-afb2-e66d50be6b05/resourceGroups/rg-prd-oem-2208081500/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic-prdnteuoms01"
  }
  "02" = {
    "nic_id" = "/subscriptions/2bc7b65e-18d6-42ae-afb2-e66d50be6b05/resourceGroups/rg-prd-oem-2208081500/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic-prdnteuoms02"
  }
}
```

lb.tf
The key line here is 'network_interface_id = each.value.nic_id'.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nibapa" {
  for_each                = var.nic_ids
  network_interface_id    = each.value.nic_id
  ip_configuration_name   = "internal"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lbap.id
}
```

Simples when you know how ;-)